Code of conduct violation
Just for information
A friend challenged the status quo and was given a notice of retaliation, asked to leave the premises. The parties involved were the president, CFO and HR. She reached out to the parent company’s compliance department, which reports to the CEO of the parent company. The president and CEO have a close relationship. The compliance department began an investigation, but it was influenced by the president. During the investigation, while she was advocating for fairness, they were discussing a future golf trip that had been booked. Despite strong evidence in her favor, the investigation's results were against her. Isn’t this violation of code of conduct where compliance Officers should act independently without bias? In this case compliance was sharing information with the management. The timing of booking of the golf trip with the CEO clearly indicates that the president was communicating with the CEO during the ongoing investigation.

Depends on where this happened, how the challenge was made, what the code of conduct says, etc. Many codes of conduct are self-imposed, that is different from ethics codes imposed from outside. Your friend needs a lawyer, who can then be told the details. Law SE cannot give legal advice.

Employee discipline must give procedural fairness
australia
The rules of procedural fairness or natural justice "are flexible, requiring fairness in all the circumstances, including the nature of the power exercised and the statutory provisions governing its exercise."
The fact that the CEO and president have a close personal relationship and were in communication about other matters is not, on its own, an indication that there wasn't procedural fairness.
In addition, since the president was a witness to the incident, one would expect that they would "influence" the outcome through their testimony. Further, it is not a breach of procedural fairness for the president to have an opinion on the correct outcome and to state that opinion.
While influence is fine, undue influence is not. So, if the outcome was dictated by the president or the CEO rather than allowing the decision maker to reach their own conclusion, that would be a breach of procedural fairness. But talking about a golf trip isn't that.
